# Avoiding PhantomData in a struct to enforce type constraints

Tags: rust

I'm trying to develop a kind of batch system. Within that I'd like to use some kind of `Process` struct, which owns all process related parts. The current implementation uses `PhantomData` to enforce the type constraints:

```
pub struct Process<P: Producer<U>, T: Transformer<U, V>, C: Consumer<V>, U,V> 
{
    producer: P,
    transformer: T, 
    consumer: C,
    p1: PhantomData<U>,
    p2: PhantomData<V>,
}
```

The idea is that type emitted by the `Producer` will be used by the `Transformer` (maybe to a different type) and consumed by the `Consumer`. Therefore the types must match.

The `Process` struct should own the items implementing the `Producer`, `Transformer` and `Consumer` traits. I think that's why I need to use type parameters. Since I cannot use the the trait directly like

```
...
producer: Producer<U>,
...
```

because of the unknown size at compile time.

Is there a better way of doing this? I'm pretty new to Rust, so I might be thinking in the wrong direction.

The solution works, but it looks a bit odd with those `PhantomData` fields. Maybe that is just what `PhantomData` is used for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of type parameters, you want associated types:

```
trait Producer {
    type Output;
    fn produce(&self) -> Self::Output;
}

trait Transformer {
    type Input;
    type Output;
    fn transform(&self, val: Self::Input) -> Self::Output;
}

trait Consumer {
    type Input;
    fn consume(&self, val: Self::Input);
}

struct Process<P, T, C>
    where P: Producer,
          T: Transformer<Input = P::Output>,
          C: Consumer<Input = T::Output>
{
    producer: P,
    transformer: T,
    consumer: C,
}

impl<P, T, C> Process<P, T, C>
    where P: Producer,
          T: Transformer<Input = P::Output>,
          C: Consumer<Input = T::Output>
{
    fn run(&self) {
        let a = self.producer.produce();
        let b = self.transformer.transform(a);
        self.consumer.consume(b);
    }
}

struct MakeNum;
impl Producer for MakeNum {
    type Output = u8;
    fn produce(&self) -> u8 { 41 }
}

struct AddOne;
impl Transformer for AddOne {
    type Input = u8;
    type Output = u8;
    fn transform(&self, val: u8) -> u8 { val + 1 }
}

struct PrintNum;
impl Consumer for PrintNum {
    type Input = u8;
    fn consume(&self, val: u8) { println!("Value was {}", val) }
}

fn main() {
    let process = Process {
        producer: MakeNum,
        transformer: AddOne,
        consumer: PrintNum,
    };

    process.run();
}
```

Although I wouldn't normally add the `where` clause on the `struct` proper, I'd just have it on the `impl` which would also have a `new` method that ensures the constraints just as well.

Comment: wow, thanks! that is exactly what I was looking for and it doesn't look like abusing PhantomData anymore ;)